# Logging every time a command is run

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts, log

I want to log every time I run a certain type of command in the terminal. For example, every time I run:

```
sudo apt-get install [something]
```

I want to add *[something]* to a log file in my home directory that will look like the following:

```
[timestamp] [something]
2012-10-02 mysql-server
2012-10-03 ruby1.9.1
2012-10-06 gedit-plugins
2012-10-07 gnome-panel synaptic
```

What's the easiest way to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this would be to replace `apt-get` with a wrapper script which would log the data into a logfile and then invoke `apt-get` passing it all the parameters the wrapping script received (and returning the return code the original program returned).

If you're careful to mimic the behaviour of the original command very closely, nobody would notice any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any use of `sudo` on the system will already be logged in `/var/log/auth.log`. That file also contains other authorization-related information (see [more details here about log files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Authorization_Log)).

Sudo also logs more than just the timestamp, but also the user who invoked sudo, the working directory, and more. If you want to just extract the uses of `apt-get install` and only log the package name, this would do it:

```
zcat /var/log/auth.log* | awk  '/apt-get install/ {print $1 " " $2 " " $16}'
```

I don't know if the formatting of the date is important to you, I didn't bother since including that in the commandline above would have made it longer and less readable. But if you want have a longer bash script which converts the format, `date -I -d "Apr 27"` will convert it for you.

(By the way, your user must be a member of the `adm` group in order to read `/var/log/auth.log`. If you see `Permission denied` then you may need to prepend the grep command with `sudo`, or add yourself to the group with `sudo addgroup USERNAME adm` where USERNAME is your user name.)